# IP protection by inserting an obfuscated expiry code

Tags: c#, obfuscation

Assume I have a code where I give an update (i.e. I get paid annually for the code) once a year. I want to build in an expiry date as a means for IP protection and as a mechanism against getting cheated out of any contractual deal.

In particular, I want to obfuscate in my code an expiry year like the following:

If (current year <= 2024)
{
// do something useful
}
else
{
// do something dummy
}

My code is fairly long (say 5000 lines), mostly on purpose - so it’s not that easy to understand as such. Nonetheless, I want to build in some code where if my deal falls through in a year (say this year is 2022 and I get cheated out in 2023), then the client can only use the code until another year (say 2024).

As a part of my deal, I do an annual refresh. So if I’m still getting paid in 2023, I.e. I’m not yet cheated out of my deal, then I can replace “current year <= 2024” by “current year <= 2025”.

Is there any easy way to hide a year number like 2024 or 2025 in my code - so that in case my client tries to look through the code, he is not able to find out an obvious hard-coded year?

In particular, I’m looking for a mathematical formula or a regex like expression or something similar ?

I tried to Google a lot , but I didn’t find anything that exactly answers my problem.

If it helps, my code is in C# and as per the agreement with my client, they want the actual code (not a compiled DLL). The client is known to randomly fire guys like me once they feel they no longer need me (and can keep using my code without paying me) - such a behavior is common in our industry.

(My sincere apologies if this is the wrong forum, but my livelihood depends on this.)

Comment: What does obvious mean to you (or he)? Is `Math.Round(Math.Tan(89.9716918))` obscure enough?

Comment: Even if you obfuscate the year, the chances are pretty good that where the check is happening (even if unclear how the check works) will be fairly obvious. They can just replace all the complication with `true` and be done. Really, your strongest defences are contractual, not technical. If you own the copyright in the code and have not granted rights to the client, then them modifying the code with a *simple unobfuscated* check is still precisely as illegal.

Comment: Or to put it another way - ask yourself if you're going to solve a problem that the entire games industry struggled with for decades until it became feasible to keep the valuable bits on *their own servers*.

Comment: As long as the full code is in customer's hands and you don't have rights over it, probably not. Better find a more reasonable customer, or just switch to another place that has better environments.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, copyright protection is really difficult, and something entire companies have been built around. But most protections have been circumvented anyway.

Obsfucation tool can help, but it can also make debugging problems a pain, and may be against contracts if you promise to deliver source code.

If you deliver the source code it will make circumvention easier, but more important is if the customer has the competency & motivation to actually cheat. To make this more difficult you could perhaps sprinkle some code throughout the code base, say `If (current year <= (2020 + 4)) throw ...` in as many places as possible, making it more difficult to find all checks, but this would just increase the effort needed to circumvent the checks, not make it impossible, or even difficult really.

I would suggest that you should either:

1. Sell a license that does not require annual payments, This would obviously require a larger up-front payment, and smaller payments for annual feature updates or other maintenance.
2. Put the source code in escrow instead of having it as a deliverable. This would release the source to the customer if your company goes bankrupt or becomes incommunicable, but otherwise remain inaccessible. Ideally protecting both parties. This would at least make reverse engineering a bit more difficult.
3. Keep some critical functionality as a online service. So if the communication with the service is blocked or circumvented, the program will not work correctly.